# Looping over a bash array to add new data with jq -- only seeing the last change

Tags: bash, jq, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a Bash script that uses jq and a for loop to iterate through an array, grab a directory that I need to be monitored by Amazon CloudWatch, and stick it into the latter's JSON configuration file. However, for some reason, only the last item in the array is actually being written. I assume there's something in my logic that is not appending my changes, and instead overwriting them in a particular place, but I can't quite figure out the fix.

Here is my code:

```
logPaths=("/shared/logs/application/application1"
          "/shared/logs/application/application2" 
          "/shared/logs/application/application3")

# Loop through array to create stanzas and export them to the temp file
for i in ${logPaths[@]}; do
    jq "
      .logs.logs_collected.files.collect_list[-1] |= . + {
        \"file_path\": \"$i\",
        \"log_group_name\": \"/aws-account/aws/ec2/syslogs\",
        \"log_stream_name\": \"$definedElsewhere\",
        \"timestamp_format\": \"%b %d %H:%M:%S\"}" \
      /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json \
      > /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json.tmp \
      && cp /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json.tmp /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json
done
```

When this is executed, and I look at amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json, only a record for the 3rd entry in the array (/application3) appears in the configuration file.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] which we can copy paste and reproduce the issue.

Comment: This is part of broader code - and the original config file would be included in that - for a highly-sensitive environment. I really can't provide more than what I already have, because even if I go through the motions to sanitize it, it wouldn't really be reproducible. I think what I've provided should hopefully explain the issue well enough, and the logical error is probably right in the JQ command within the for loop.

Comment: Why would you run a separate copy of jq for each new item?

Comment: Anyhow -- a [mre] doesn't require the original file. It requires the _simplest possible_ file that your code will accept as input. If you're generating a file that contains confidential input, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: BTW, `for i in ${logPaths[@]}` has all the bugs of `for i in ${logPaths[*]}`. To avoid them, you need to quote your expansions: `for i in "${logPaths[@]}"`

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your bug -- but it's irrelevant, because if this were correctly written there wouldn't *be* any loop needed at all.

Using `jq --args` allows the `logPaths` array to be passed in as a set of positional arguments, and referred to from within the relevant jq code as `$ARGS.positional`. Thus:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

logPaths=("/shared/logs/application/application1"
          "/shared/logs/application/application2"
          "/shared/logs/application/application3")

# Make up some sample input, since the OP didn't provide any
cat >old.json <<'EOF'
{
  "logs": {
    "logs_collected": {
      "files": {
        "collect_list": [
          {"test": "make sure this old data is retained"}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
EOF

jq --arg definedElsewhere "Other Value" '
  ($ARGS.positional | [
    .[] | { "file_path": .,
            "log_group_name": "/aws-account/aws/ec2/syslogs",
            "log_stream_name": $definedElsewhere,
            "timestamp_format": "%b %d %H:%M:%S"
          }]) as $newLogSinks |
    .logs.logs_collected.files.collect_list += $newLogSinks
' --args "${logPaths[@]}" <old.json >new.json && mv new.json old.json
```

...which correctly emits as output:

```json
{
  "logs": {
    "logs_collected": {
      "files": {
        "collect_list": [
          {
            "test": "make sure this old data is retained"
          },
          {
            "file_path": "/shared/logs/application/application1",
            "log_group_name": "/aws-account/aws/ec2/syslogs",
            "log_stream_name": "Other Value",
            "timestamp_format": "%b %d %H:%M:%S"
          },
          {
            "file_path": "/shared/logs/application/application2",
            "log_group_name": "/aws-account/aws/ec2/syslogs",
            "log_stream_name": "Other Value",
            "timestamp_format": "%b %d %H:%M:%S"
          },
          {
            "file_path": "/shared/logs/application/application3",
            "log_group_name": "/aws-account/aws/ec2/syslogs",
            "log_stream_name": "Other Value",
            "timestamp_format": "%b %d %H:%M:%S"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code. The customer in this case is extremely sensitive about their code being shared. It's not that confidential data is part of the script, it's just that the customer doesn't really care about if the security violation actually puts them at risk, just that a violation occurred. I digress - how can I also append the file_path to the end of the log stream name? I tried adding the period like you have for file_path, but this resulted in a compile error.

Comment: @JoshEdgar, what security violation? I gave an example of a [mre] here, above, with `{"logs":{"logs_collected":{"files":{"collect_list":[{"test":"make sure this old data is retained"}]}}}}`. I wasn't asking you for any kind of confidential work product at all.

Comment: @JoshEdgar, anyhow, so are you saying you want to put `$definedElsewhere + "/shared/logs/application/application1"` in your variable, or `definedElsewhere + "application1"`, or something else? (This could easily get into the space where it really ought to be a separate question; insofar as nothing in the original question appears to call for it, we might be at that point already).

Comment: @JoshEdgar, ...or if `/shared/logs/application/` is a fixed prefix, maybe you only put `application1`, `application2` and `application3` in your array, and in both places add that suffix to a fixed prefix. _shrug_; depends on what you personally need.

Comment: Basically, $definedElsewhere contains an AWS account number and instance ID, let's assume that is /12345/i-67890/. But in the JSON, the log_stream_name needs to be set to /12345/i-67890/shared/logs/application/application1. So in addition to how the array value is being put in by itself to file_path, it also needs to be appended to the end of the $definedElsewhere baseline path that represents this specific EC2 instance for log_stream_name.

Comment: Great; sounds like either concatenating the strings with `$definedElsewhere + .` or using something like `"\($definedElsewhere)\(.)"` will work for you. That said, if you want a _tested_ answer on how to do that, ask a separate question with a [mre] focused on just that one narrow issue..